# Backendless - How To Get Objects From 'Data'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, backendless

How do I get all the objects from Backendless's database into a UITableView in my iOS app?
Looking at their Documentation, it doesn't clearly state how to get all objects. (I'm new to the platform)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: genuinely not getting you point. can you please give some more details?.. like back endless database is your web database or cloud database or local database?

Comment: It is cloud database

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it in Swift (for my table of Blurb objects):

```
  func retrieveBlurbs() {
    let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
    // Use backendless.persistenceService to obtain a ref to a data store for the class
    let dataStore = self.backendless.persistenceService.of(Blurb.ofClass()) as IDataStore
    dataStore.find(query, response: { (retrievedCollection) -> Void in
      print("Successfully retrieved: \(retrievedCollection)")
      self.blurbs = retrievedCollection.data as! [Blurb]
      self.tableView.reloadData()
      }) { (fault) -> Void in
        print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    }
  }
```

I am also new to Backendless and really enjoying it! It's a lot like Parse, but better in a bunch of ways.

Comment: That why I'm moving to Backendless as it has similar features to Parse due to the sad news of it retiring in 2017.
Would you know by any chance what this is in Objective-C?

Comment: You can find many of the same methods I am calling in objective-c [here in their documentation](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_basic_search.htm) I recommend looking at what I do, and then finding the objective-c equivalent in the examples shown in those docs.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:
https://backendless.com/feature-16-data-retrieval-api-how-to-load-objects-from-an-mbaas-storage/

Then move on to this: https://backendless.com/feature-17-data-paging-or-how-to-efficiently-load-large-data-sets-in-a-mobile-app/

Both articles include concrete examples in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self getDataFromBackendless];
}

-(void)getDataFromBackendless {
    @try {
        BackendlessCollection *documents = [backendless.persistenceService of:[YOUR_TABLE_NAME class]];
        currentPage =[documents getCurrentPage];
    }
    @catch (Fault *fault) {
        NSLog(@"Server reported an error: %@", fault);
    }
}
```

Then perform UITableView methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      return [currentPage count];
}
```